# Why is my Button Click event only firing one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, button, event-handling

I have looked around on the net and have not been able to find a relevant solution to this.

I have created a simple .net web application that reads data from a local Access database. The connection works as it reads the first row and populates the textboxes.

When I click the button it reads and populates the second row but then it stops working and will not read the next row of data. I am not getting any errors or build problems. The button just stops working! Is there something with the event handler that I am missing?

Solved by using `IsPostBack` to see if the page was loaded before and ViewState to store positions value across button clicks/ page reloads.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" EnableClientScript="False"/>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {       
        private OleDbConnection connection;
        private OleDbCommand command;
        private OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        private DataSet dataset;
        private string firstname;
        private string lastname;
        private int age;
        private int position;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection();
            command = new OleDbCommand();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dataset = new DataSet();

            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\People.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1";

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "Table1");

            ShowValuesOfRow(0);
        }

        private void ShowValuesOfRow(int pos)
        {
            DataRow row = dataset.Tables["Table1"].Rows[pos];
            position = pos;

            firstname = row["FirstName"].ToString();
            lastname = row["LastName"].ToString();
            age = (int)row["Age"];

            TextBox1.Text = firstname;
            TextBox2.Text = lastname;
            TextBox3.Text = age.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int lastIndex = dataset.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Count - 1;

            if (position < lastIndex)
            {
                position++;
                ShowValuesOfRow(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although Gary.S is spot on, you might learn more by placing a breakpoint in your onclick handler and inspecting the values on each submission.

Comment: Agreed, debugging is key to answering your own questions.

Comment: You're grabbing all rows from the database, and showing them by one after each button click. That seems like an unusual interface; why are you doing it that way in the first place?

Comment: @chris, tried inserting breakpoints but it wasn't explaining why the button stopped working

Comment: @Gary - I agree, I'm just not very good at it ;)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the position variable. Every time you click the button the page goes through the entire life cycle again and re-initializes position to 0 (this goes for all variables). One way you can work around this is to use viewstate to store position between postbacks.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx

Example:

```
public int Position
{
    get
    {
        int? position = null;
        if (ViewState["Position"] != null)
        {
            position = ViewState["Position"] as int?;
        }
        return position ?? 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Position"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see @Ray K, this won't work if pos is always reset on postback

Comment: Agreed, you should initialize variables that are persisted only once. You do that by checking !Page.IsPostBack and initializing there (setting `Position = 0`) as @Ray K mentions

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked great. Ended up using a combination of IsPostBack and ViewState to store position's value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into using the

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```

in your page load... every time the button is clicked, the page load runs and resets your dataset.

Also, use a static variable for 'pos' it is also probably reset every time.

(Be careful about static variables if multiple users are using this page at the same time... if that's the case, look into session variables)

Comment: How about skipping the static variables and recommending the [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx) (thread-safe) approaches only.

Answer (score 0):

Important fact you need to understand in web development is that everything you do on web in terms of request/response is stateless - the variables are not persisted in memory between individual requests (in constrast to desktop form applications). You always need to use different approach like ViewState, Cache, Session or HTML hiddent input elements.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help, got me thinking about how the variable's value was persisting across button-clicks / page reloads.

Comment: Yes, and if you always bear in mind that web request/response model is stateless, it will considerably make your development decisions easier, because it will be always clear what is persisted (with inputs, ViewState, etc.) and what isn't.